# What is "Christ Consciousness"?

Tags: belief, spirituality, religion

I have heard this term used and would like more info about this idea. It really sounds like a hippie thing...

Comment: Are you sure this is not a New Age/Gnostic/Buddhist interpretation of Jesus Christ? Such an interpretation revives a version of an old Gnostic heresy that Jesus the man was somehow possessed by Christ, and giving it a Buddhist twist, by saying that just as Siddartha became the Buddha and Jesus became the Christ, we too, all of us could reach this higher enlightened consciousness, alternatively called Buddha consciousness or Christ consciousness.

If this is it, it has nothing to do with Christianity.

Comment: @theodoulos i don't know, but i'm not interested in the New Age view. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: You might want to cite a few verses of Paul that mention "the _mind_ of Christ."

Comment: @Andrew +1 thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Christ Consciousness" is a neo-pagan term used by those who don't believe that Jesus was ***the*** Christ but who attack Christianity with the purpose of diluting the word *Christ* through misuse, claiming that we all have a "Christ Consciousness" and that religious gurus of all religions have had this "Christ Consciousness" in some measure beyond normal people.  In other words, there is absolutely nothing Christian about the phrase "Christ Consciousness."